# WiFi or Bluetooth to get directions

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible using WiFi or Bluetooth to know where the hotspot is ?
I mean, from my mobile, know the distance and the bearing to head to it.

Comment: By looking at the `RSSI`, but that only give you a "circle", and not a precise one.

Answer (score 0):

A single and static phone can hardly localize a hotspot. However, it may be achieved by multiple phones which cooperate with each other.

Moreover, I believe that Google has a database with the rough locations of static APs identified by SSID or MAC address all over the world. The RSSI values and locations (got from GPS or cellular network) are reported to a Google server by Android OS periodically - I guess. So you can achieve your goal if you have access to that database.